# how i know which object call the event vb.net / C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have two timers I AddHandler to ShowData

how I know which timer call the event

```
 Dim TM1, TM2 As System.Timers.Timer

        TM1 = New Timers.Timer(600000) 
        AddHandler TM1.Elapsed, AddressOf ShowData
        TM1.Start()

        TM2 = New Timers.Timer(15000) 
        AddHandler TM2.Elapsed, AddressOf ShowData
        TM2.Start()


 Private Sub ShowData()
  Dim T as string
  T =   ' here I want object name that called this event 
 'code         
 End Sub
```

Comment: That code won't even compile.  Edit your code to make it correct, then re-post it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the [correct signature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.elapsedeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx), then you have the `sender`-argument which is the timer:

```
Private Sub ShowData(sender As Object, e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
    Dim timer = CType(sender, System.Timers.Timer)
    If timer Is TM1 Then

    ElseIf timer Is TM2 Then

    ElseIf timer Is TMEmail Then

    End If
End Sub
```

For the sake of completeness(and your C# tag):

```
private void ShowData(Object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    var timer = (System.Timers.Timer) sender;
    if(timer == TM1)
    {

    }
    else if (timer == TM2)
    {

    }
    else if(timer == TMEmail)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: That work good but I have other problem

when I try make this on object come from other class give me this msg :

   does not have signature compatible with delegate

Comment: @user2842091: your next problem is not clear, maybe you should ask another question and include an example.